# LDAP autentication issue with joomla in IIS on windows server

Tags: iis, joomla, ldap

I am seting a joomla site on IIS server to configure with Active Directory IIS

somehow I am not able to bind into LDAP..It gives error such as = "10304 - Failed to bind LDAP user"..

any help appreciated....

Comment: Did you google the error message? Did you try different configurations? This is like the first hit on google: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Extension_talk:LDAP_Authentication/Failed_to_bind_user - perhaps post your configuration (whithout passwords, but with the bind strings)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply..somehow I got it work at the end..It was just the issue in the parameters specified..